# Word order of subordinate clauses starting with “welche”

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause, interrogative

What should be the word order after forms of *welcher?*
Should I put the verb at the end of the sentence or is its correct as shown below?

> Ich möchte gern wissen, welche Bedingungen soll man erfüllen.

Answer (score 5):

The point is not whether "welche" appears in a sentence. The point is what type of sentence you're forming.

> Welche Bedingungen soll man erfüllen?
>
> Ich möchte wissen, welche Bedingungen man erfüllen soll.

As you see, a subordinated clause has the finite verb at the end, while a main clause has it in the second slot of the sentence. All the question words with "w-" can be used to construct both main clauses and subordinated clauses, so they are useless as an indicator of verb position.

Answer (score 0):

The position of "welche" is correct. The word order of your verb in the subordinate clause isn't. It has to be

> Ich möchte gern[e] wissen, welche Bedingungen man erfüllen soll.